# nginx code to redirect www.homepage.com/index.html to www.homepage.com?

Tags: php, web, nginx, server, hosting

NGINX index.html homepage redirect is needed, which will:

redirect:

https://homepage.co.uk/index.html

to:

https://homepage.co.uk

(without causing an infinite loop)

```html
location = /index.html { return 301 homepage.co.uk/$1; }
```

UPDATED (Working Solution):

```
location /index.html {
    if ($request_uri = /index.html) {
        rewrite ^ http://$host? permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ceejayoz Please help? :)

Comment: Try removing the `$1`. It makes little sense having it there. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675743/nginx-rewrite-rule-to-remove-index-html-from-the-request-uri.

Comment: location /index.html {
        if ($request_uri = /index.html) {
            rewrite ^ http://$host? permanent;
        }
    }

Thanks for that link, the code above works perfectly :)